# How can Play Video file in android for specific time

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, playback

I have four MP4 videos. And I want to play all of them one by one. Each video should play 
for a specific time for example 30 second. I have code like this:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

videoView.setVideoPath(PATH_TO_FILE);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

videoView.start();
```

How can I change this code to run 4 videos one by one, and each video is played 
for 30 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be checking for it's current position in a handler like this

```
private android.os.Handler mHandler;
private Runnable mRunnable;

mHandler = new Handler();
mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {     
        int currentPostion = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition());       
        if(currentPostion >= 30 * 1000 || currentPostion == mVideoView.getDuration()) {
           // Play next video        
        }
        mHandler1.postDelayed(this, 250);      
    }
};
mHandler.post(mRunnable);
```